# Compiler error when using Boost.Python with CUDA NVCC on OSX

Tags: python, c++, boost, cuda, boost-python

I was trying to write a python extension using Boost.Python and accelerate with CUDA. But I got a compiler error simply by compiling a file that includes the Boost.Python library:

```
// test.cu
#include <boost/python.hpp>
```

I compile it with

```
nvcc test.cu -c -o test.o -ccbin /usr/bin/clang -DNVCC \
    -I/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/include -I/opt/local/include \
    -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
```

The following error appears

```
/opt/local/include/boost/python/args.hpp:88:29: error: return type of out-of-line
      definition of 'boost::python::detail::keywords_base::operator,' differs
      from that in the declaration
keywords_base< nkeywords> ::operator,(const arg &k) const
                            ^
/opt/local/include/boost/python/args.hpp:52:35: note: previous declaration is
      here
inline keywords< nkeywords + 1UL> operator,(const arg & k) const;
                                  ^
/opt/local/include/boost/python/args.hpp:100:29: error: return type of
      out-of-line definition of 'boost::python::detail::keywords_base::operator,'
      differs from that in the declaration
keywords_base< nkeywords> ::operator,(const char *name) const
                            ^
/opt/local/include/boost/python/args.hpp:55:35: note: previous declaration is
      here
inline keywords< nkeywords + 1UL> operator,(const char * name) const;
                                  ^
```

I am using Boost.Python version 1.57 and python version 2.7.9, both installed with MacPorts. My CUDA toolkit version is 7.0.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does using clang directly produce an error on this file?

Comment: @T.C. Nope, `/usr/bin/clang` compiles `test.cu` fine.